# Python Gtk3 Window Icon from SVG / scalable icon from stock theme

Tags: python, icons, gtk3

How to set an high quality icon to Gtk.Window ?
My theme has SVG icons, but I always get an pixel size of 24 px. So what is wrong with my code? Would be very happy for some help. Thanks

[image]

**Max size is always 24**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

icon_name = "applications-mail"
icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()

found_icons = set()
for res in range(0, 512, 2):
    icon = icon_theme.lookup_icon(icon_name, res, 0)
    found_icons.add(icon.get_filename())
print("\n".join(found_icons))
sizes = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().get_icon_sizes(icon_name)
max_size = max(sizes)
print("max size = {} ({})".format(max_size, sizes))
pixbuf = icon_theme.load_icon(icon_name, max_size, 0)
window.set_default_icon_list([pixbuf])

window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

**Response**:

```
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/categories/22/applications-mail.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/categories/48/applications-mail.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/categories/96/applications-mail.svg
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/categories/32/applications-mail.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/categories/16/applications-mail.png
/usr/share/icons/Mint-X/categories/24/applications-mail.png
max size = 24 ([22, 16, 24])
```

Answer (score 2):

I could be mistaken, here are some ideas:

- I don't have *any* icon on my machine called "applications-mail". I did find many "internet-mail" icons though.

> /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/categories/96/applications-mail.svg

- Also, I believe svg icons should be in a `scalable` directory. Possibly the svg you did find wasn't recognized as such. Eg. I have:

`/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/apps/internet-mail.svg`

- I modified your program slightly:

Listing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        #icon_name = "applications-mail"
        icon_name = "internet-mail"
        icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()

        found_icons = set()
        for res in range(0, 512, 2):
            icon = icon_theme.lookup_icon(icon_name, res, 0)
            #print(icon)
            if icon != None:
                found_icons.add(icon.get_filename())

        if len(found_icons) > 0:
            print("\n".join(found_icons))
            sizes = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().get_icon_sizes(icon_name)
            max_size = max(sizes)
            print("max size = {} ({})".format(max_size, sizes))
            pixbuf = icon_theme.load_icon(icon_name, max_size, 0)
            self.set_default_icon_list([pixbuf])

        self.show_all()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

and I get:

```
/usr/share/icons/Tango/24x24/apps/internet-mail.png
/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/apps/internet-mail.svg
/usr/share/icons/Tango/16x16/apps/internet-mail.png
/usr/share/icons/Tango/32x32/apps/internet-mail.png
/usr/share/icons/Tango/22x22/apps/internet-mail.png
max size = 32 ([22, 16, 24, 32, -1, 0])
```

where -1 indicates a scalable icon. (so, don't use `max()` - look for -1.
This from the [developers' site](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkIconTheme.html#gtk-icon-theme-get-icon-sizes):

> [gtk_icon_theme_get_icon_sizes] Returns an array of integers describing the sizes at which the icon is
>   available without scaling. A size of -1 means that the icon is
>   available in a scalable format.

**edit**: More ideas:

- Gtk uses gdk-pixbuf.loaders modules to render images such as icons. You might not have the svg driver working correctly. I also seem to recall that the librsvg libraries is necessary.
- Even if another icon is actually working, you might be seeing a copy from the icon cache, and your icon renderer might still be failing.
- There might even be a problem with the icon cache itself. Try [rebuilding the cache](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-update-icon-cache.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can also use other icon name or theme. But even if I use theme "gnome" and icon "mail-send-symbolic" , which is only available as a scalable icon, I get only low resolution. Also with your example :-(
The reason I used max is that I want to show that not even 32 or 48 is in the list. I use Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04) and I will update my system next days to Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04) and then I will try it again.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Gtk uses gdk-pixbuf.loaders modules to render images such as icons. You might not have the svg driver working correctly. There has been some confusion with different drivers. I also seem to recall that the librsvg libraries are necessary. Note that once gtk shows an icon, I believe it is converted to png, and shows indepently from the .svg... BTW, did you try moving the png to /scalable/? (there are some interesting hints in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107465, and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141072)